# Unable to log user state information to transcript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I am using TranscriptLoggerMiddleware and CosmosDB to log my chatbot transcripts. We are trying to capture the user state information (user name, account number, account type, etc) as top level attributes in the transcript so that specific customers can easily be queried in the DB (if that information is just in the individual timestamp attributes of the document, they can't be queried).

Ideally I would just add the user state when I'm building the file, but I can't figure any way to access it since the logger is defined in index.js and TranscriptLoggerMiddleware only provides the `activity` to my function, not the full `context`. If anyone has a way to get the user state data via TranscriptLoggerMiddleware, let me know, that would solve this issue. Here is the customLogger code. Note that due to the function receiving both the user query and bot response, I couldn't get retrieving and resaving the transcript to work, so I'm overwriting the transcript from a local log object. Not trying to come up with a new approach here but if one would solve the overall issue I'd like to hear it.

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const { CosmosDbPartitionedStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * CustomLogger, takes in an activity and saves it for the duration of the conversation, writing to an emulator compatible transcript file in the transcriptsPath folder.
 */
class CustomLogger {
    /**
     * Log an activity to the log file.
     * @param activity Activity being logged.
     */
            
    // Set up Cosmos Storage
    constructor(appInsightsClient) {
        this.transcriptStorage = new CosmosDbPartitionedStorage({
            cosmosDbEndpoint: process.env.COSMOS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT,
            authKey: process.env.COSMOS_AUTH_KEY,
            databaseId: process.env.DATABASE,
            containerId: 'bot-transcripts'
        });
           
        this.conversationLogger = {};

        this.appInsightsClient = appInsightsClient;

        this.msDelay = 250;
    }
        
        
    async logActivity(activity) {
        
        if (!activity) {
            throw new Error('Activity is required.');
        }
        
        // Log only if this is type message
        if (activity.type === 'message') {
            
            if (activity.attachments) {
                try {
                    var logTextDb = `${activity.from.name}: ${activity.attachments[0].content.text}`;
                } catch (err) {
                    var logTextDb = `${activity.from.name}: ${activity.text}`;
                }
            } else {
                var logTextDb = `${activity.from.name}: ${activity.text}`;
            }
            
            if (activity.conversation) {
                var id = activity.conversation.id;
                if (id.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
                    id = activity.conversation.id.replace(/\|.*/, '');
                }
                      
                // Get today's date for datestamp
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var day = currentDate.getDate();
                var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
                var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
                var datestamp = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                var fileName = `${datestamp}_${id}`;
        
                var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1);
                
                // CosmosDB logging (JK)
                if (!(fileName in this.conversationLogger)) {
                    this.conversationLogger[fileName] = {};
                    this.conversationLogger[fileName]['userData'] = {};
                    this.conversationLogger[fileName]['botName'] = process.env.BOTNAME;
                }
            
                this.conversationLogger[fileName][timestamp] = logTextDb;
            
                let updateObj = {
                
                    [fileName]:{
                        ...this.conversationLogger[fileName]
                    }
                
                }
            
                // Add delay to ensure messages logged sequentially
                await this.wait(this.msDelay);
            
                try {
                    let result = await this.transcriptStorage.write(updateObj);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.appInsightsClient.trackTrace({message: `Logger Error ${err.code} - ${path.basename(__filename)}`,severity: 3,properties: {'botName': process.env.BOTNAME, 'error':err.body}});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    async wait(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
exports.CustomLogger = CustomLogger;
```

Not being able to get user state in this function, I decided to try a few other approaches. The most promising was creating a separate "updateTranscript" function to grab the transcript, add user state, and save it back. But I think it was catching it only on user request and getting overidden again by local object on bot response. I added a delay to try to combat this, but it still didn't work. On my very first prompt of providing customer number user state data is getting stored on transcript, but at the next activity it is gone and never comes back (even though I can see it is supposedly getting written to DB). Here is that update function.

```js
const { CosmosDbStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

var updateTranscript = async (context, userData, appInsightsClient) => {
    const transcriptStorage = new CosmosDbStorage({
        serviceEndpoint: process.env.COSMOS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT,
        authKey: process.env.COSMOS_AUTH_KEY,
        databaseId: process.env.DATABASE,
        collectionId: 'bot-transcripts',
        partitionKey: process.env.BOTNAME
    });

    var id = context.activity.conversation.id;
    if (id.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
        id = context.activity.conversation.id.replace(/\|.*/, '');
    }

    // Get today's date for datestamp
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var datestamp = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    var filename = `${datestamp}_${id}`;

    var msDelay = 500;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msDelay));
    
    var transcript = await transcriptStorage.read([filename]);

    transcript[filename]['userData'] = userData

    try {
        await transcriptStorage.write(transcript);
        console.log('User data added to transcript');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        appInsightsClient.trackTrace({message: `Log Updater Error ${err.code} - ${path.basename(__filename)}`,severity: 3,properties: {'botName': process.env.BOTNAME, 'error':err.body}});
    }

    return;
}

module.exports.updateTranscript = updateTranscript
```

I realize this approach is a bit of a cluster but I've been unable to find anything better. I know the Microsoft COVID-19 bot has a really nice transcript retrieval function, but I haven't been able to get any input from them on how that was accomplished. That aside, I'm quite happy to continue with this implementation if someone can help me figure out how to get that user state into the transcript without being overwritten or running into concurrency issues.

As to why I can't query an account number even via `substring()` function, here's an example of the documents data object. I have no idea which string to check for a substring, in this case 122809. I don't know what that timestamp could be. If this is stored at the top level (e.g. userData/accountNumber) I know exactly where to look for the value. For further context, I've displayed what I see after the first prompt for account number, where userData is populated. But it gets overidden on subsequent writes and I can't seem to get it back even with a delay in my updateTranscript function.

```js
"document": {
        "userData": {},
        "botName": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA",
        "1594745997562": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA: Hi! I'm the OEM CSC Support Bot! Before we get started, can you please provide me with your 6-digit Vista number? If you don't have one, just type \"Skip\".",
        "1594746003973": "You: 122809",
        "1594746004241": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA: Thank you. What can I help you with today? \r\nYou can say **Menu** for a list of common commands, **Help** for chatbot tips, or choose one of the frequent actions below.  \r\n  \r\n  I'm still being tested, so please use our [Feedback Form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=lVxS1ga5GkO5Jum1G6Q8xHnUJxcBMMdAqVUeyOmrhgBUNFI3VEhMU1laV1YwMUdFTkhYVzcwWk9DMiQlQCN0PWcu) to let us know how well I'm doing and how I can be improved!",
        "1594746011384": "You: what is my account number?",
        "1594746011652": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA: Here is the informaiton I have stored: \n   \n**Account Number:** 122809 \n\n I will forget everything except your account number after the end of this conversation.",
        "1594746011920": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA: I can clear your information if you don't want me to store it or if you want to reneter it. Would you like me to clear your information now?",
        "1594746016034": "You: no",
        "1594746016301": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA: OK, I won't clear your information. You can ask again at any time."
    },

"document": {
        "userData": {
            "accountNumber": "122809"
        },
        "botName": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA",
        "1594746019952": "AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot_QA: Hi! I'm the OEM CSC Support Bot! What can I help you with today? \r\nYou can say **Menu** for a list of common commands, **Help** for chatbot tips, or choose one of the frequent actions below.  \r\n  \r\n  I'm still being tested, so please use our [Feedback Form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=lVxS1ga5GkO5Jum1G6Q8xHnUJxcBMMdAqVUeyOmrhgBUNFI3VEhMU1laV1YwMUdFTkhYVzcwWk9DMiQlQCN0PWcu) to let us know how well I'm doing and how I can be improved!"
    },
```

Comment: Can you link to the Microsoft COVID-19 bot you're talking about?

Comment: Here is the link to the blog article that introduced the bot: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/updated-on-5-24-2020-quick-start-setting-up-your-covid-19/ba-p/1230537

Comment: Okay I tried out the health bot but I'm not sure what transcript retrieval functionality you're referring to. I'm also still unsure what you're trying to do and why. It looks like you're trying to store user state alongside your transcripts, but what's wrong with how the user state is stored normally? What data is in the user state? Are you trying to duplicate the entire user state in each turn and store that as a sort of snapshot? Do you want every activity in the transcript to have a state object or just user-to-bot activities? I wonder if inspection middleware will help.

Comment: When you type `log`, the healthcare bot can retrieve transcripts not just from your current conversation, but others as well (assuming userID is the same). While it's not an exact parallel to what I'm doing, clearly somehow the transcripts are being stored and I'm sure it is a more effective method than I am using, and would definitely help my issue since it seems to know userID.

Comment: The main requirement is that the customer's account number can be queried in DB so that all transcripts from that account can be retrieved. The account number is prompted on welcome, but it can also be provided later (or cleared and changed). The way we have implemented transcripts (with `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`), I can't find any way to insert this value without running into concurrency issues. And as it is, since account number is a substring of one attribute (timestamp) of the document, there is no way to query with Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: If there is any way to see the source on how Microsoft handled transcripts for the health bot, I think I could probably figure out a solution. But there is almost no documentation on transcripts (and virtually none for nodejs), so I've had to try to solve this myself using only TranscriptLoggerMiddleware and a `customLogger` sample that was removed months ago from Github (and was originally just for logging locally to a file).

Comment: Oh the user state you want to log is just one piece of metadata? I had the wrong impression since bot state can be very large and can accumulate more data on each turn, like with the dialog stack. I don't understand why the account number is related to the timestamp, but it sounds like what you're calling a timestamp contains more data than just a timestamp. I also don't understand why you can't query the substring, since it looks like Azure Data Explorer provides that ability: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction

Comment: I did try the `log` command in the health bot now, and I can see that it does seem to have saved transcripts, but I doubt it's doing anything special to save and retrieve them. That functionality can be achieved with `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware` normally. It seems like the health bot team has made sure to keep their source code proprietary, and even if I did access it for you I don't see how it would yield the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I think it would have helped in that my logger (using `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`) is very unstable. When I just so much as added a read call to Cosmos in the logger, it stopped capturing both turns. Really any sample of a stable transcript feature in nodejs would give me a better building block than I have today. But for now we've got something working. We just need to figure out how we can incorporate our user data into the transcript so that it is queryable.

Comment: You haven't explained why it's not queryable now. Is there a reason the substring function I linked to isn't working in your case? Would it be queryable if you were to put the account number in your activity's properties or entities and then access the account number in the logger so that it could be in the object you're saving to Cosmos DB?

Comment: Yes, if somehow the account number or other user data were available in the activity, I think it should work. But I already do some modifications on the activity (e.g. for removing Teams bot mentions before sending to LUIS), and those are not present in the logger since I presume as soon as the activity is sent it goes to the logger. As far as substring, the problem is that I don't know which string to look at. Each user/bot response is a separate attribute with a timestamp. I'll add an example to the main question.

Comment: Okay thank you for the example because this clears up a huge misunderstanding. You had said "account number is a substring of one attribute (timestamp)" which sounds like you have an object with a property like `{ 'timestamp': '1594746003973-122809' }`. It made no sense at all why you'd have a property that contains an account number when it's supposed to contain a timestamp. So what you meant is that your documents use timestamps as property keys, and the only place you could find the account number is in a substring of the value of one of those properties and you don't know which one.

Comment: I also see that you're not associating user state with each message, so why do you want to do it in the transcript logger middleware? If you only need to save the account number to Cosmos DB once, you can do that at the same time it gets saved to user state, can't you?

Comment: That's the rub. In practice the user request and bot response happen almost simultaneously. The only way I could get this to work was by saving the request/response locally and then overwriting the current object in Cosmos. If I try to read the existing transcript, append, and write back, I run into concurrency issues and/or only one side of the conversation (bot or user) is logged for each turn.

Comment: I had thought Cosmos has builtin ways to deal with concurrency, and I figure you could use a lock in your bot code anyway. But more importantly, if you're awaiting your read/write operations then why would they happen concurrently? You should already have written the incoming message before getting to the outgoing message. That said, it's still true that you should buffer the things you need to write and only write to Cosmos once per turn. Bot state handles this automatically. Do you think it would work to keep the transcript in user state instead of using the storage class directly?

Comment: Cosmos has eTag element which is supposed to help deal with this. But I think the issue is that the adapter calls the logger twice per turn. I'm not certain but I don't see how else it could be working since the logger code only logs one activity (see in Q, just one activity from and activity text). This has led to all sorts of issues. That's why I was hoping to see the transcript function on Health Bot (I think PVA has something similar), because I can't figure out a way to handle it. What I have now mostly works but any changes seem to break the capture of both query and response.

Comment: As for User State, I still would have to be able to access state from the logger (via `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`), and as of now I can't see how I could access state in that function else I would have already tried to grab the account number from there.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Been out of office. Will check this week and advise if there are any further issues.

Comment: Hello, have you checked yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had said you were encountering concurrency issues even though JavaScript is single-threaded. As strange as that sounds, I think you're right on some level. [`TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/transcriptLogger.ts#L114-L135) does have its own buffer that it uses to store activities throughout the turn and then it tries to log all of them all at once. It could easily have provided a way to get that whole buffer in your own logger function, but instead it just loops through the buffer so that you still only get to log them each individually. Also, it allows `logActivity` to return a promise but it never awaits it, so each activity will get logged "simultaneously" (it's not really simultaneous but the code will likely jump between function calls before waiting for them to complete). This is a problem for any operation that isn't atomic, because you'll be modifying state without knowing about its latest modifications.

> ```
> while (transcript.length > 0) {
>     try {
>         const activity: Activity = transcript.shift();
>         // If the implementation of this.logger.logActivity() is asynchronous, we don't
>         // await it as to not block processing of activities.
>         // Because TranscriptLogger.logActivity() returns void or Promise<void>, we capture
>         // the result and see if it is a Promise.
>         const logActivityResult = this.logger.logActivity(activity);
>
>         // If this.logger.logActivity() returns a Promise, a catch is added in case there
>         // is no innate error handling in the method. This catch prevents
>         // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarnings from being thrown and prints the error to the
>         // console.
>         if (logActivityResult instanceof Promise) {
>             logActivityResult.catch(err => {
>                 this.transcriptLoggerErrorHandler(err);
>             });
>         }
>     } catch (err) {
>         this.transcriptLoggerErrorHandler(err);
>     }
> }
> ```

All in all, I don't think transcript logger middleware is the way to go here. While it may purport to serve your purposes, there are just too many problems with it. I would either write my own middleware or just put the middleware code directly in my bot logic like this:

```
async onTurn(turnContext) {
    const activity = turnContext.activity;
    
    await this.logActivity(turnContext, activity);
    
    turnContext.onSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, next) => {
        for (const activity of activities) {
            await this.logActivity(ctx, activity);
        }
        
        return await next();
    });

    // Bot code here

    // Save state changes
    await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext);
}

async logActivity(turnContext, activity) {
    var transcript = await this.transcriptProperty.get(turnContext, []);
    transcript.push(activity);
    await this.transcriptProperty.set(turnContext, transcript);
    console.log('Activities saved: ' + transcript.length);
}
```

Since your transcript would be stored in your user state, that user state would also have the account number you need and hopefully you'd be able to query for it.

Comment: I think I will try going the route of adding in onTurn. To make sure I understand, the `turnContext.onSendActivities` will call the log function after every activity the bot sends? It seems in this way since the calls are awaited I could even call my existing logger which saves to Cosmos? It will be easier for the business to access transcripts there than extract from userState/blob storage so I may try that first but I want to make sure I understand how the `onSendActivities` is working.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This is essentially how middleware works, and there's not much difference between running code in middleware and running code in your main bot logic.

Comment: And to be clear, you can still use Cosmos DB for your bot state. If you're writing to storage without using bot state then you'll need to worry about caching the state if you want to avoid writing many times per turn, and you'll need to come up with your own way to distinguish between users in your database. Bot state automatically handles a lot of things you'll need to do.

Comment: I was finally able to implement this and it appears to be solving the issues of getting the customer data into the transcript as well as having the last activity from the bot sometimes dropped. I'm going to add another answer with some clarification on my solution for reference, but I will accept this one since the onTurn function is what makes this work and will apply to a number of different approaches developers might take.

Comment: Side note, I do realize potential benefits of using state to store transcripts, there just isn't any documentation on how to split activities into separate conversations, have them easily readable (lines of text or a way to render the activities), be able to search for specific conversations on a number of criteria like date and customer number, etc. The Healthcare Bot seems to take care of these things and has a really nice interface, but I haven't been able to get any answers on even what approach is used, much less any code or templates to try to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle's answer did help me solve the issue, and I think that will be the most reusable piece for anyone experiencing similar issues. The key takeaway is that, if you're using nodejs, you should not be using TranscriptLoggerMiddleware and instead use Kyle's function in your onTurn handler (repeated here for reference):

```js
// Function provided by Kyle Delaney
async onTurn(turnContext) {
    const activity = turnContext.activity;
    
    await this.logActivity(turnContext, activity);
    
    turnContext.onSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, next) => {
        for (const activity of activities) {
            await this.logActivity(ctx, activity);
        }
        
        return await next();
    });

    // Bot code here

    // Save state changes
    await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext);
}
```

You need to note, though, that his `logActivity` function is just storing the raw activities to the user state using a custom `transcriptProperty`. As of yet I haven't found a good method to give business/admin users access to this data in a way that is easily readable and searchable, nor construct some sort of file out output to send to a customer requesting a transcript of their conversation. As such, I continued using my `CustomLogger` instead. Here is how I accomplished that.

First, **you must create the transcriptLogger in the constructor**. If you create it inside your turn handler, you will lose the cache/buffer and it will only have the latest activity instead of the full history. May be common sense but this tripped me up briefly. I do this in the constructor via `this.transcriptLogger = new CustomerLogger(appInsightsClient);`. I also modified my `logActivity` function to accept the userData (my state object) as a second, optional parameter. I have successfully been able to use that userData object to add the required customer information to the bot transcript. To modify Kyle's function above you just need to replace `this.logActivity` with your function call, in my case `this.transcriptLogger.logActivity(context, userData);`.

While there are still some other issues with this approach, it does solve the title question of how to get user state data into the transcript.